# angularjs watchcollection previous value

Tags: angularjs

### Update

This issue has been resolved in 1.3.0 beta: see the [commit](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/78057a945ef84cbb05f9417fe884cb8c28e67b44)

---

I have an array I'd like to listen for changes on and compare the new value to the old value. The docs for $watchCollection (http:// docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootScope.Scope), say that the callback takes three parameters, the first one being the new collection and the second being a copy of the former value. It seems that the same array is being passed to both parameters, instead of the new and old values.

In this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/pEpQE/2/), the same array is passed to the new value and former value, whether I'm pushing values onto the array, setting the variable to a new array, or editing an element of the array. All 3 examples trigger the watch listener, but none contain the former value in the callback.

I am able to get the results I want with this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/pEpQE/1/). It uses the $watch(obj, listener, equality) method with true as the third parameter. Shouldn't $watchCollection provide this functionality as well?

```
$scope.$watchCollection("arr", function(newVal, oldVal) {
    //here, oldVal should contain a copy of the former value,
    //but it is the same as newVal
});
```

Comment: Reading the documentation I get the same understanding you do, and I am able to replicate the results in this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Mf2i2lRyEGzJWTQrmVPS?p=preview). Might be a bug or the docs need to be rewritten

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:** Sorry about the previous answer.

But it seems it's a open issue in the AngularJs repository with the exact same problem.

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/2621

Best of luck.

Comment: Not to be rude, but that fiddle is exactly the same as my [second example](http://jsfiddle.net/pEpQE/1/) - I had found the same workaround as you; I was just wondering why $watchCollection wasn't doing the same thing

Comment: @David I'm truly sorry!! I think I missed it, I assumed it was the same problem that happened to me and forgot to read thoroughly. I'll edit my answer. Good luck though.

Comment: No problem! And good find with the issue - that is it exactly.